# Node.js / mongoDB, cannot retrieve records

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

In my node.js / express app, when I look into mongoDB, I got the following:

```
 > db.things.find()[0]._id                                
 ObjectId("4da06702584ca3f402000001")
```

It does exists a collection with id 4da06702584ca3f402000001. But When I use a request, I cannot get it back:

```
app.get('/thing/show', function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  Thing = mongoose.model('Thing');
  id = "4da06702584ca3f402000001";
  Thing.find({ _id : id }, function(thing){
     console.log("THING RETRIEVED:" + thing);
     res.write(JSON.stringify(thing));
  });
  res.end();
});
```

Nothing is returned.

Any idea ?

*** UPDATE ***

This does not work either:

```
Thing.find({ _id:ObjectId("4da06702584ca3f402000001")}, function(thing){
```

It raises the following error:

```
Error: This is an abstract interface. Its only purpose is to mark fields as ObjectId in     the schema creation.
 at ObjectId (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/mongoose/1.1.24/package/lib/mongoose/schema.js:426:9)...
```

*** SOLUTION ***

My bad....

The problem is not with the find function but with the callback method I use... I only provided one single parameter (thing) where I should provide (err, tring).

Comment: try `mongoose.model('thing')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the callback function where I should have used (err, thing) as parameters instead of only (thing).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Thing.findById(id, function(thing){
```